# WSL: Trouble running turtlesim_node

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I get the following error when I'm trying to run the turtlesim_node in the beginner tutorial. I'm using ROS melodic on the Linux subsystem for Windows 10 and using tmux to run my multiple terminal sessions.

Error message:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326692/wsl:-trouble-running-turtlesim_node/) by [thepac](https://answers.ros.org/users/43375/thepac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sean Yen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37768/sean-yen/) on 2019-06-24**:
In cases you are not aware of this, if you are looking a ROS installation working on Windows, there is a Windows version of Melodic ready to use. http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WSL cannot run graphical applications out-of-the-box. You'll need to install an X server on the Windows side.

People appear to have had success with VcXsrv or xming.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-23**:
Please note that ROS on WSL is not a supported combination and it's always unclear how well the networking stack is working in WSL. You may run into issues, even with a working X server setup.

**Comment by [thepac](https://answers.ros.org/users/43375/thepac/) on 2019-06-23**:
Yes, I installed VcXsrv and it appears to work, somewhat. I think I'll have to do some more research to tweak it to work with no error messages. The GUI at least works. Thank you!!